# How can I bind the transforms of Viewport2DVisual3D controls in code-behind?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm tasked with creating something of a 3D interface for an application. After looking through my options I decided Viewport2DVisual3D was the easiest to understand and use with my game design background (I am comfortable with matrix transformations, etc).

So far I've got a nice list of buttons displaying in a semicircular 'stage' sort of pattern onscreen. This is a good start. Now, what I want to do is allow the carousel to rotate with user input. For now, I'd have a button rotate into center view when clicked, but eventually I'll use manipulation data to allow the screen to be swiped about.

The issue I'm having is binding the Transform property of each V2DV3D to the data backing each Button control. I am not sure how to do this in code-behind, and it needs to be code-behind in order to programmatically build the transforms.

As it is, I assign the value this way (`vv` is a `Viewport2DVisual3D` object):

```
vv.SetValue(Viewport2DVisual3D.TransformProperty, item.Transform);
```

Where `item` is a `CarouselItem` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class CarouselItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [...]

    public Transform3DGroup Transform
    {
        get { return _transform; }
        set { _transform = value; OnPropertyChanged("Transform"); }
    }

    [...]

    private void Recalc()
    {
        Transform3D rotate = new RotateTransform3D(new 
            AxisAngleRotation3D(CarouselBrowser.Up, angle));
        Transform3D translate = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 0,
            CarouselBrowser.Radius);
        Transform3D translate2 = new TranslateTransform3D(
            CarouselBrowser.Focus);
        Transform3DGroup tGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
        tGroup.Children.Add(translate);
        tGroup.Children.Add(rotate);
        tGroup.Children.Add(translate2);
        Transform = tGroup;
    }

    [...]

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
    /// a public property with the specified name. This 
    /// method does not exist in a Release build.
    /// </summary>
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
    /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
    /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might 
    /// override this property's getter to return true.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

    [...]
}
```

(some code omitted; `Recalc` is called when `angle` is changed, and the new value *is* different than the old)

So the initial 'binding' works fine, the buttons take their initial transformations, but any further modifications to Transform result in no change. The event handler for the Transform property change event has no subscribers. How should I change the binding/relationship with CarouselItem and V2DV3D to get them to link? There doesn't seem to be any sort of DataContext or similar property of V2DV3D I could bind the whole object to.